# Laravel5.5 error after merging branch: Failed opening required file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, tortoisesvn, voyager

After merging branch, I am facing this error.

> lluminate\Support\ServiceProvider::mergeConfigFrom(): Failed opening required 'D:\project_folder_path\vendor\larapack\voyager-hooks/publishable/config/voyager-hooks.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

All composer update/installs  failed with same error below.

> Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
>
> In ServiceProvider.php line 59:
>
> lluminate\Support\ServiceProvider::mergeConfigFrom(): Failed opening required 'D:\project_folder_path\vendor\larapack\voyager-hooks/publishable/config/voyager-hooks.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

Line No 59 in ServiceProvider.php

```
/**
 * Merge the given configuration with the existing configuration.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  string  $key
 * @return void
 */
protected function mergeConfigFrom($path, $key)
{
    $config = $this->app['config']->get($key, []);

    $this->app['config']->set($key, array_merge(require $path, $config));
}
```

Comment: See this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-does-mergeconfigfrom-work  May be it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

**Try composer autoload files.**
`composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Not working, same error : Generating optimized autoload files Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump @php artisan package:discover

In ServiceProvider.php line 59:

lluminate\Support\ServiceProvider::mergeConfigFrom(): Failed opening required 'D:\project_folder_path\vendor\larapack\voyager-hooks/publishable/config/voyager-hooks.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')

Comment: try to composer self-update after that you can try above command

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

I noticed both slash styles are being used in this path:

```
D:\project_folder_path\vendor\larapack\voyager-hooks/publishable/config/voyager-hooks.php
```

I would check if that file even exists first.

**Original**

It's failing to merge the updated config file for voyager into your existing config file. Compare these two files:

```
D:\project_folder_path\vendor\larapack\voyager-hooks/publishable/config/voyager-hooks.php
```

And the one in your project:

```
D:\project_folder_path\config\voyager-hooks.php
```

It is likely you have lines that are two similar for the merge to know what to do with.

Comment: There is no "voyager-hooks.php" in D:\project_folder_path\config\ and no publishable folder under "D:\project_folder_path\vendor\larapack\voyager-hooks/"

Comment: `'D:\project_folder_path\vendor\larapack\voyager-hooks/publishable/config/voyager-hooks.php' ` This has to be the problem. It's using both windows and unix style directory separators. Is there a custom service provider in your app that is doing this merge?

Answer (score 0):

Those files was deleted, if you are using git, you can restore that folder. check with `git status`, then restore with `git restore` or `git checkout`. But i dont know reason why are deleting.